# Latin Hypercube around set points

Tags: mathematical-statistics, latin-hypercube

Is there a method for constructing a LHC around set points? For example, I want to test a component in a system and I have enough time to run 20 conditions. I expect that in the system, the component will experience conditions different 5 conditions (correlating to set points 1-5) the majority of the time. This leaves me with 15 points remaining which I would like to use as a LHC around points 1-5 to give me an idea of how it would operate.

I'm aware that I could ignore the 5 set points and run a LHC with the 15 samples points and accept that these won't be significantly different from the set points but this isn't particularly efficient. Is there a way to run a LHC around the 5 set points I have to test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Yes. One method is outlined in a [vignette](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/lhs/vignettes/augment_lhs.html) for the R-package [lhs](https://cran.r-project.org/package=lhs). The example starts out with a Latin hypercube design and then augments the design with new points, but the same procedure would also work with an arbitrary set of points. Depending on where the original points are, you may or may not end up with a Latin hypercube overall.